# Find the number of dentists so less than a specific number of patients are waiting at specific time t

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

[image]
Historical data:

[image]

Am I right to think about this question from the perspective of Poisson Distribution? I think I have to find something like $P(X\le 3)$, but I don't know how to find $\lambda$, the mean number of occurrences in this case.

In this case, we need to make sure there are less than $3$ patients at a specific time $t$.

How do you find the number of dentists so less than a specific number of patients are waiting at specific time t?

Comment: Firstly, you can never make sure of this $-$ however many dentists you have, there will always be a chance, however small, that more than three people will have to wait in line. Secondly, we are missing too much data anyway. For instance, how many patients are expected in a typical hour?

Comment: Added the historical data, they don't allow more than 3 people to wait in the line. The case already specified that. @TonyK

Comment: What on earth are those arrival times? Are you measuring them to the ten-thousandth of a minute? Anyway, now you have to decide what is an acceptable probability threshold for the chance of having to turn away a patient in, say, a given day. This should be some small number, maybe 0.001 (but its exact value is a business decision, not a mathematical one).

Comment: Yes. We are only concerned about the mathematical value though, that's how it was thrown to us by the professor.

Answer (score 1):

First of all get an estimate of the inter-arrival rate from the dataset. Calculate interarrival times as $I_i=a_i-a_{i-1}$ where $a_i$'s are arrival times and $a_0=0$. Then $\hat\lambda=\frac{n}{\sum I_i}.$ Now let's say that only $m$ many patients are allowed to wait and you want $n$ many dentists. So, at a time $t$ you want inter-arrival less than or equal to $m+n$ between time $(t-10,t]$, otherwise, the clinic has to return some patients. So, you want $N_t-N_{t-10}\left(\stackrel{d}{=}N_{10}\right)\leq m+n.$ Now $N_t-N_{t-10}\sim \textbf{Poi}(10\hat\lambda)$ and as @TonyK mentioned in the comment that there is no way you can make sure that with probability one. However, you can do it for expectation or quantiles.

For an example, if you want on an average how many dentists you need then you answer should be $E(N_t-N_{t-10}\leq m+n)\Rightarrow 10\hat\lambda\leq m+n\Rightarrow n\geq 10\hat\lambda-m.$

Again if you want how many doctors you need such that with probability at most $p$ the clinic don't have to return a patient, then find the smallest non-negative integer $k_0$ such that $P(N_{10}>k_0)\leq p.$ Then the answer should be $n\geq k_0-m.$

Comment: $p$ is the probability the clinic doesn't have to turn away a client _over which time period_? (And less importantly, is $n$ the number of arrival times, or the number of dentists?)

Comment: $n$ is the number of dentists, and apparently, if you fix any time $t$ then by memoryless property probability that the clinic has to turn away a patient doesn't depend on time $t$. And I am looking at the marginals.

Comment: @John_Wick I have come up with the result using your method, we need to hire exactly 2 dentists. Can you confirm if my result is correct?